# Python lazy dict with iterator in constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, hash-map, lazy

This question began as an off-topic answer to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/86122/95400), but the code here serves a different goal.

I wrote the following class for the purpose of populating a dict on demand from an iterator. The intent of the iterator passed to the constructor is that it could alternatively be passed to `dict`, which would consume the entire iterator in its constructor; an instance of this class consumes the iterator just far enough to locate a requested item. Such an iterator would be similar in spirit to a return value from `dict.items`.

```
class LazyDict(dict):
    """ A dict built on demand from an iterator """

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        super().__init__()
        self.iterator = iterator

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        while not self.get(item):
            try:
                (key, value) = next(self.iterator)
                self[key] = value
            except StopIteration:
                raise AttributeError
        return super().__getitem__(item)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        try:
            self[item] # pylint: disable=pointless-statement                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            return True
        except AttributeError:
            return False
```

Here is my calling code (with other details of the `Directory` code omitted; if more of that is needed in this context I can provide it):

```
class Directory(object):
    @Lazy
    def hash(self):
        """ Lazy dict mapping entry names to entries """
        return LazyDict((self.name(entry), entry) for entry in self.readdir())

    def __contains__(self, name):
        return name in self.hash # pylint: disable=unsupported-membership-test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.hash[name] # pylint: disable=unsubscriptable-object
```

The code for `Lazy` is equivalent to `lazy_property` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849299/5384908).

As I write this, it occurs to me that perhaps `Directory` should itself be a subclass of `LazyDict` rather than containing a `LazyDict` (that might be a better way to stifle those `pylint` warnings). Whether that seems right might be one specific question to fall out of this. Upon further investigation, here is an alternate version of the calling code:

```
class Directory(LazyDict):
    def __init__(self, mem, size):
        super().__init__((self.name(entry), entry) for entry in self.readdir())
        self.mem = mem
        self.size = size
```

As before, some details of `Directory` are omitted (the implementations of `name` and `readdir` are not included for either version), but this version of the code inherits `__getitem__` and `__contains__` from `LazyDict` rather than overriding them. The most visible difference between the two versions of the calling code is due to `Directory` inheriting `__repr__` from `dict` rather than `object`.

Another specific question might be the role of `keys` and `values` and `items` in `LazyDict`. The methods inherited from `dict` reveal how much of the iterator has been consumed; convincing them to reveal all items is one `AttributeError` away (I can attempt to fetch `self[None]` within `Directory` to fully populate the cache). My inclination is to limit on-demand operations to `__getitem__` and `__contains__`, but opinions on that point are welcome.

Suggestions for other ways to approach this are also welcome.

Comment: Can you describe a use case for this data structure?

Comment: The `Directory` class mentioned here is part of a module which lists contents of a `squashfs` image. `Directory.__getitem__` is used for directory lookups. If only `readdir` is called on a directory (to list all of its entries), there is no need to populate the cache used for lookups within that directory.

In a large directory, the time saved by not populating that cache unnecessarily might be significant.

Comment: Hi, I rolled back your edit. Please see [What you may and may not do once you've received answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Design

I think that it's a mistake to inherit from `dict`. My reasoning is as follows:

1. `LazyDict` is effectively read-only: that is, setting an item does not update the underlying iterator. (In the described use case, you can't update the compressed file image through this dictionary.) So it is misleading to offer (as you do) a `__setitem__` method (and similarly for `update`, `pop`, `setdefault` and other mutating methods).
2. Programmers are used to the equivalence of dictionary methods: for example, they "know" that `d.get(k)` behaves just the same as `d[k] if k in d else None`. But in your implementation it does not — calling `d.get(k)` does not consult the iterator but calling `k in d` or `d[k]` does. This seems like a recipe for confusion and bugs.

So I think the better approach is not to inherit from `dict`, but to have a dictionary as an attribute. This means that users will only be able to call the methods that you choose to implement, instead of accidentally calling through to methods on the underlying `dict`. This approach also makes the code clearer, because you can distinguish `key in self` from `key in self._dict` without needing to use `super()` or have pylint annnotations.

#### 2. Other review comments

1. The parameter to the `__getitem__` and `__contains__` methods would be better named `key`.
2. The exception raised from a failed key lookup should be `KeyError`, not `AttributeError`, for consistency with `dict`.
3. The exception raised on a failed key lookup should include the failed key, for consistency with `dict` and to help programmers track down errors.
4. It's a good idea to keep `try: ... except: ...` blocks as small as possible, so that you don't accidentally capture exceptions that you weren't expecting. In this case you are expecting a `StopIteration` from the call to `next` so that's the only line that needs to be protected.
5. It's conventional to give attributes that are not intended to be used outside of the class (like `iterator`) the prefix `_`.

#### 3. Revised code

```
class LazyDict:
    """A dictionary built on demand from an iterator."""
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self._dict = {}
        self._iterator = iterator

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return self._dict[key]
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        while key not in self._dict:
            try:
                k, v = next(self._iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                return False
            self._dict[k] = v
        return True
```

Now someone who tries to call the `get` method will get an exception instead of silently getting the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of `LazyDict` which incorporates some of the recommendations in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132731/95400) (thanks, Gareth!):

```
class LazyDict(dict):
    """ A dict built on demand from an iterator """

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        super().__init__()
        self.iterator = iterator

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item in self:
            return super().__getitem__(item)
        else:
            raise KeyError(item)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        while not super().__contains__(item):
            try:
                (key, value) = next(self.iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                return False
            self[key] = value
        return True
```

Consuming the iterator in `__contains__` rather than in `__getitem__` eliminates the `pylint` cruft, as well as the call to the `get` method. Minimizing the `try:` block protects only the call to `next`. Raising `KeyError` instead of `AttributeError` is consistent with `dict` behavior.

This version still inherits the `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` (and other) methods from `dict`, which allows it to provide a copy-on-write cache of the underlying iterator. In a `squashfs` application, that might provide the basis for an image editor in which the final step of saving the modified image consists of generating a new image from the contents of the cache.